# How to build multiple configurations in VisualStudioOnline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to build multiple configurations, e.g. Debug, Release, in VisualStudioOnline.

Found some guides doing this online (e.g. [here](http://donovanbrown.com/post/How-to-build-multiple-configurations-in-a-single-VSTS-build), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37136923/how-to-handle-multiple-configurations-in-vsts-release-management)) but they all end up with "Under the Options tab, enable Multi-configuration".

Problem is I have no such entry in the options tab.
[image: No multi-configuration option]

Is it a licensing thing? Do I need to enable it somewhere else? Has this functionality been removed or replaced with something else?

Comment: It looks like it is something in Visual Studio Team Services, whatever that is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refer to this screenshot and check it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. A bit confusing but there is link to an example in "more information" so I'm sure I can work it out.