# Cypress Across Multiple Machines [Azure Devops]

Tags: javascript, azure, automation, devops, cypress

I have 20 windows 10 VMS and have about 700 solo cypress tests and I want a way to be able to spread all these tests across the 20 VMs so the tests run a lot faster is this possible and how also take into mind I need to run a Jar, as well as that, is what builds the website that the cypress tests are run on. Any suggestions to speed up these processes? I am also using Azure DevOps as that is the company standard to run these automation tests.

Comment: Just curious, are you using self-hosting Azure DevOps Server?

Comment: They are not Azure DevOps server they are just servers within the company that can be accessed though Azure DevOps so they are just standard machines with the azure agent.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any additional paid services (like Cypress.io's dashboard service), I think the strategy is to:

1. divide your 700 tests into several subsets, then
2. run these subsets on multiple agents in parallel.

To accomplish #1, you could either use several Cypress configuration files and hardcode a specific subset of tests using the `testFiles` property, or you could create a script that selects dynamically determines the tests (based on some parameter) and then uses the [Cypress module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api.html#cypress-run) to actually run your tests.

Regardless of which approach you take with #1, you'll have to use ADO multi-configurations (see SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535607/8754516), which gives a guide on how to set up and use them) in order to accomplish #2. Essentially, ADO multi-configurations allow you to define the same set of tasks that can be run on multiple agents, while passing a `Multiplier` argument to each of those agents. This `Multiplier` argument is just a comma-separated string, for example, `'testSet1,testSet2,testSet3'`. However, each agent will receive only 1 of those values, for example, the first agent might receive `'testSet1'`, the second agent might receive `'testSet2'`, etc.

So now, you can imagine that each agent performs the setup of your application and then runs a subset of the Cypress tests depending on which argument it receives (`'testSet1'`, `'testSet2'`, etc.).

Last, you might want to collate the test results so that you can publish them. I'd recommend outputting the test results into a generated, deterministic folder in a shared network drive for each of the test runs. For example, if you had 3 agents running the 700 tests, they could publish their test result XML's into the `//shared-drive/cypress/results/<date>` folder. Then, you would have a final, separate agent job that would collate the test results and publish them.

Comment: Thank you, I already do it this way but had the problem some tests run longer then others such as 250 in one 250 in another 250 in another so 750 being ran but the second 250 tests might take 30mins where the first 250 tests may take 10minutes so wanted to spread it out better but looks like it isn't possible without a paid subscription so I will just keep it as is thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can/want to set up the infrastructure, there is [sorry-cypress](https://sorry-cypress.dev/) that you should check out. It has many of the features of cypress' paid service, most importantly parallelization with load balancing.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps you can set up [agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) to handle this. Then you can define a pipeline job and tell ADO to run it in [parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#multi-job-configuration), pointing at your pool of agents.

Additionally, you will need to pay for [Cypress.io's dashboard service](https://www.cypress.io/pricing), which will enable [parallel test execution](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization.html#Overview).

Once everything is in place, you'll need to run the tests with the `--record` and `--parallel` flags. Cypress.io's service will act as the orchestrator to tell each machine which tests to run, and to combine all the test results together.

Comment: Is there a method that doesn't need to be paid for as I can produce the results on Azure Devops?

Comment: For Cypress tests I don't know of any free off-the-shelf way to parallelize your tests. You'd have to create your own system of choosing a subset of tests for each machine, then combining the results into something meaningful.